# How do I make components in React Native without using JSX?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

The canonical way of using React Native is apparently with JSX:

```
render: function() {
  var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
      <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
      <Image source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

How would I do this using JavaScript only? Typically in normal React, `React.createElement('div')` would work as an alternative to JSX, but I get an error "null is not a function" when trying to run my iOS React Native app.

Comment: Have you looked at the result of compiling the JSX to pure JS? That should give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: From JSX to JS that runs in the React Native iOS project, this is all a transparent operation to me. I don't know how to grab only the JSX to JS compilation step.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried contacting the packager, which says it listens on port 8081 and also says that it is getting requests for `index.ios.bundle` as it runs.

So I put this in my browser: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle

In the returned bundle, I found:

```
var wazoo = React.createClass({displayName: "wazoo",
  render: function() {
    return (
        React.createElement(View, {style: styles.container}, 
          React.createElement(ScrollView, null, 
            React.createElement(View, null, 
                React.createElement(Text, {style: styles.welcome}, 
                  "Wazoo"
                ),
```

And so on. So it looks like `View`, `ScrollView` etc. are just like components as defined as usual in Web React, and the above code is the JS equivalent to the JSX.

Comment: Does this work with strings? as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002382/react-native-create-element-with-string

Comment: I see this is the React.createElement

Answer (score 16):

Daniel Earwicker's solution is correct, but we can use Factories to make it more readable:

```js
var View       = React.createFactory(React.View);
var ScrollView = React.createFactory(React.ScrollView);
var Text       = React.createFactory(React.Text);

var wazoo = React.createClass({displayName: "wazoo",
  render: function() {

    return View({style: styles.container}, 
      ScrollView(null, 
        View(null, 
          Text({style: styles.welcome}, 
            "Wazoo"
          )
        )
      )
    );


  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the original question but, in case someone else is interested, you could check the library we made at Uqbar:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/njsx

It's quite easy to use and provides a cleaner interface than the React out-of-the-box interface.