# react native create element with string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval, ecmascript-6, react-native

I see a lot people creating a route mapping in React native similar to the below:

```
if (route.id === 'Blah') {
    return  (<Blah prop1={this.method} prop2={this.other method} />);
} else if (route.id === 'OtherView') {
    return (<OtherView prop1={this.method} />);
}
```

this can quickly become many lines of code, I'd like to do something like this:

```
return (React.createElement(route.id, {propsToPass}));
```

This doesn't work in React Native as apparently 'strings are not allowed as the first parameter in React Native since those are meant to be used for html tags in regular React.'

So how can this be done? I got it working if I supply a ReactClass as the first param, or with eval(route.id) (but I know that can be dangerous).

How can I create a React Native element with a string?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid JS.

Comment: If you're talking about the JSX component in the conditionals in the first code snippet, then that's because it hasn't been compiled into JS, which is how React works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup an allowed components namespace:

```
var routeComponents = {
  "Blah": Blah,
  "OtherView": OtherView
}

if(routeComponents[route.id]) {
  return React.createElement(routeComponents[route.id], {propsToPass});
} else {
  // Error
}
```

Comment: I like the routeComponents[] idea, I didn't see how this[route.id] works... can you explain a bit more?

Comment: After thought, this[route.id] is not something you could do, so I have removed it from my answer.

Comment: Right ok, I was hoping for a safe way to transform a string but ill mark this as correct as it's probably the best way